# Is there a statement expression equivalent in Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc

GCC has a statment expression feature that allows macro to be defined as:

```
#define maxint(a,b) \
   ({int _a = (a), _b = (b); _a > _b ? _a : _b; })
```

This is illegal in Visual Studio.

Is there an equivalent feature in microsoft visual studio?
(I know, I would better use GCC. But I am just curious).

Or, do we just have to resort to inline functions?

Comment: Inline functions aren't necessarily a last resort. Using templates, you can get similar performance and type-safety. I'd take that any day.

Comment: Wait, how is this different than `a > b ? a : b`? Also @drdwilcox he's using C not C++ so templates aren't an option.

Comment: @Seth Your macro evaluates twice

Comment: @Seth a and b are copied to temporaries so that the macro a and b are evaluated only once.

Comment: Correction: It's not "this is illegal in Visual Studio", it's "this isn't allowed in C (or C++)". The short answer, however, is no. If you want an inline function, that's what you should use.

Comment: Statement expressions are not legal in ANSI C, so if you can't use C++'s inline functions, you'll have to use a macro like `#define MAX(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))` and be wary of its potential to evaluate its arguments more than once.

Comment: @fardjad I asked that exact question, it's because `a` and `b` get evaluated twice while the gcc one doesn't.

Comment: "I would better use GCC." IMO, you should better stick to standard C and use any compiler. This is exactly what the standard is for.

Comment: Well, you can use options to disable non-standard extensions

Comment: Can someone tell me then why linux kernel code uses such non-standard C features in the code? It makes the kernel code non-compilable even in standard C compilers other than gcc.

Comment: @SHH: the linux kernel doesn't care about compiler portability at all, and needs very precise control about the code generated. GCC is the only supported compiler. Kernels are rather special in this respect, they need to be portable to different hardware, but not different software environments.

Comment: Another standard-conforming way of doing this is to define a self-invoking lambda. `#define maxint(a,b) ([](int v1, int v2) -> int { return a > b ? a : b; })(a,b)`.

Comment: @Raymond: That would work in C++11 (after correcting `a` and `b` to `v1` and `v2` in the function body), but not in C.  Visual Studio's C compiler does not support lambdas, at least not in VS 2010 or the VS 2011 Developer Preview.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield Oops, missed the "C" part.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no equivalent in the MS compiler to this non-standard GCC language extension.

Comment: But isn't it weird that linux kernel uses non-standard C features in the code? It makes the kernel code non-compilable even in standard C compilers other than gcc.

Comment: That's just the path that Linux took. Kernels have different driving forces from apps.

Answer (score 6):

If you were using C++, I believe a lambda function could be used:

```
#define maxint(a,b) \
   ([=] () {int _a = (a), _b = (b); return _a > _b ? _a : _b; }())
```

Comment: Does Visual Studio support lambda functions *in C*?

Comment: Oops, sorry, didn't look at the 'C' tag

Comment: And anyway this isn't the same, e.g. in a statement expression you can return from the function but you can't do that with a lambda.

Comment: So, why not just:
```
int maxint(int a, int b) {
   return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

Comment: @chen3feng Functions have overhead in call and return.  Unless they are inlined, which is covered in the last line of the question.

Comment: And why not just #define maxint(a,b)  ([=] () {return (a) > (b) ? (a) : (b); }()) ?

Comment: @Sakuragaoka Putting a lambda function inside a define seems like the worst of both worlds. Besides, as has already been noted, a lambda function cannot return from the calling scope.